# Frontier exploration in ROS noetic

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use frontier explanation in Ros noetic. Is there a way to use in this Ros package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382295/frontier-exploration-in-ros-noetic/) by [VacumCleanerOGU](https://answers.ros.org/users/76962/vacumcleanerogu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-07-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you want to do frontier exploration, explore_lite is also a similar package but it's quite easy to setup since it only requires move_base setup. [explore_lite](http://wiki.ros.org/explore_lite) has noetic branch and you can just install it with apt-get.

---

Originally posted by [So Young](https://answers.ros.org/users/67634/so-young/) with karma: 118 on 2021-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5